# NameError: name 'My_stack' is not defined

Tags: python

Не могу понять, в чем ошибка:

stack=My_stack

NameError: name 'My_stack' is not defined

```
    class My_stack:
        def __init__(self):
        self.array=[]
    
def push(self, item):
    
    self.array.append(item)
    
def pop(self):
    popped.item = self.array.pop()
    return popped_item


def peek (self):
    return self_current()
def __current(self):
    return self.array[self.count-1]
def count(self):
    return len(self.array)

def __iter__(self):
    self.iter= self.count()-1
    return self

def __next__(self):
    if self.index<0:
        raise StopIteration()
    result=self.array[self.index]
    self.index=1
    return result
```

Comment: может `stack = My_Stack()` все таки?

Comment: Можно код полностью, с строчкой `stack = My_stack `

Comment: Zhihar, спасибо, прав!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно ваш код выглядит так:

```
stack = My_stack() 

class My_stack():
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

то есть вы пытаетесь создать экземпляр класса до инициализации самого класса

```
class My_stack():
    def __init__(self):
        ...

stack = My_stack()
```